# how to search encryption value in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, encryption, aggregate

I am trying to implement a searchable encryption in nodejs by using the encrypted index.
Here is my database.

```
    {
       "_id" : 2,
       "name" : "Anya",
       "username" : "myName",
    }
```

i tried this method too. but didn't work.
i'm new in node and try to search with encrypted value. any one have idea about how to make to solve it.

```
db.collection.find({name: "encrypted value"})
```

Comment: `i tried this method too. but didn't work` you need to be specific to get a specific answer. Properly encrypted data should look random and you are unable to search without decrypting. you could store a hash next to the encrypted value, which could allow you to look-up values

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB client-side field level encryption uses the `encrypt-then-MAC` approach combined with either a deterministic or random initialization vector to encrypt field values. MongoDB only supports the `AEAD AES-256-CBC` encryption algorithm with `HMAC-SHA-512` here what I got relevant to these MAC.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-client-side-encryption/